# The "Comment Everywhere" privilege text is somewhat misleading

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, wording

To new users I think the "Comment Everywhere" text used for that privilege might be a bit misleading.

To me it seems like the text leans towards having the ability to comment everywhere on all Stack Exchange communities.

I know, if you read the community's "Privileges" help page, it says

> "Privileges control what you can do on COMMUNITY_NAME"

specifying the community to which the privileges apply to. Also, you could tell the new user [RTFM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RTFM#Phrase) and get on with it, but I think if the privilege text read "Comment Everywhere on COMMUNITY_NAME" it would clear up some confusion.

What are your opinions on this?

Comment: Well then every privilege could be misconstrued to be granted on all sites in the network.

Comment: The other privileges have text like "vote up", not "vote up everywhere". I know that's slightly different but hopefully you get the idea. Another possible idea would be simple to just remove the "Everywhere" text from the "Comment Everywhere" text and just have the "Comment" privilege. If this is too close to the ability to comment on your own questions, then "Comment on others" might do the trick.

Comment: I honestly don't see a problem. If a user makes this misconception, they will figure it out as soon as they try to comment somewhere else.

Comment: It's not a problem, just a user experience issue.

Comment: @Firelord I've had an account for over 3 years here, I don't need the how to search link! The report was for new users who might find it misleading, not me, I'm just looking for opinions on it. So far, people tend to think the new users will just have to deal with it and find out the hard way. *edit*: I see somebody upvoted this but there was a downvote too.

Comment: Oops! I misjudged (partly) as it seems. But my opinion still stands. It wouldn't do bad if you can gather previous (if exists) similar posts to make your point more strong. Think about it. The chances of such posts being posted in the past are higher for a new user of that time so using them as background would IMO do more good than seeking consensus from non-new users (mostly)  on this post who already understand what that string means.

Comment: It's misleading in another way: you can't comment on locked posts or deleted posts, but "everywhere" includes those.